# Spring WebClient : Call method in retry

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have been looking for a solution to the following use case without success, I hope someone can help :

Assuming the following use case. I need to call a customer Api (`customerApi`) and this api needs a `Bearer` token which may have expired when I call `customerApi`. If the token has expired, the `customerApi` returns a `401` response.

What, I want to do is to retry only once if I received a `401` and call the method to get a new `Bearer` token. If the retry still returns `401`, I need to throw an `Exception`

The method to get a `Bearer` token :

```
private String getToken() {
    return oAuthService.getToken();
}
```

And the `webClient` usage to call `customerApi` (`customerWebClient` is a bean created with `WebClient.Builder`) :

```
public Customer getCustomerById(String customerId, String token) {
        return customerWebClient.get()
            .uri("myurl/customers/{customerId}, customerId)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
            })
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Customer.class)
            .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.NotFound.class, notFound ->
                        Mono.error(new MyCustomException()))
            .block();
    }
```

It seems that `retryWhen` can only be used to upgrade timeout. So I hope that someone know how to achieve this use case ^^

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT :**

I tried to use `retryWhen(Retry.onlyIf(...))` from `reactor-extra` but the good old `retryWhen` from this package is now deprecated (solution based on : [Adding a retry all requests of WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752021/adding-a-retry-all-requests-of-webclient))

Comment: I dont see any deprecation notice on any `retryWhen` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method

```java
public final Mono<T> retryWhen(Function<Flux<Throwable>, ? extends Publisher<?>> whenFactory)
```

has been deprecated and now the preferred method is

```java
public final Mono<T> retryWhen(Retry retrySpec)
```

So, you can modify your code to something like this to make it work with the new `retryWhen`

```java
public Customer getCustomerById(String customerId, String token) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);

    final RetrySpec retrySpec = Retry.max(1).doBeforeRetry(
        retrySignal -> headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + someTokenGetterMethod()))
        .filter(throwable -> throwable.getClass() == Unauthorized.class);

    return Mono.defer(() -> webClient.get().uri("myurl/customers/{customerId}, customerId")
        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Customer.class))
        .retryWhen(retrySpec)
        .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.NotFound.class,
            notFound -> Mono.error(new MyCustomException()))
        .block();
}
```

Here's a working example using https://httpbin.org/

```java
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    final RetrySpec retrySpec = Retry.max(1).doBeforeRetry(
        retrySignal -> headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer 1234")).filter(
        throwable -> throwable.getClass() == Unauthorized.class);

    return args -> Mono.defer(() -> webClient.get().uri("https://httpbin.org/bearer")
        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers)).retrieve().toEntity(Map.class)
        .retryWhen(retrySpec)
        .subscribe(objectResponseEntity -> System.out
            .println("objectResponseEntity = " + objectResponseEntity.getBody()));
}
```

Also, I do not think the way you're trying to manipulate headers in retry to add authorization token is the right way of achieving this. You must come up with a better solution/design.

Comment: Perfect solution ! Thx a lot, for the purpose that it is not the right way, I simplified the subject compare to the real use case I need to implement.

Comment: Indeed nice solution, thanks a lot @Isank