# Spring WebClient Configure Global Retry Logic

Tags: java, spring, webclient

I'm trying to configure the Spring [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) to retry on a specific exception. Specifically [PrematureCloseException](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/PrematureCloseException.html) but Im not really sure the exception matters.

[I know how set a retry policy when calling a method on the client](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-retry) but I would like to do it globally for any request that goes through the client.

I fell like I should be able to do it with an [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) but I not really familiar with this and cannot figure it out.

Comment: You can try something similar to this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752021/adding-a-retry-all-requests-of-webclient>

Comment: When I use retry() in an ExchangeFilterFunction, I get `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: multiple subscribers not supported`. So this solution won't work.