# Reactor HttpClient with retry strategy

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Right now I define retry strategy for each webClient call (like below)

```
    public ModelResponse exampleMethod() {

        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/example")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ModelResponse.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException
                                && ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()))
                .block();
    }
```

I'd like to share the same retry strategy among all WebClients calls (for different methods and http requests).

Is it possible to set retry strategy on `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` and then use it to create `WebClient` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do so by creating `ExchangeFilterFunction` to handle server error, and there define retry strategy. Although, it sounds great there are some kickbacks. Finally, I came up with solution based on [Adding a retry all requests of WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752021/adding-a-retry-all-requests-of-webclient)